# Can't get correct sums from data in a sheet either by sumif, sumifs, sumproduct or query

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a sheet where I entered all products that I have bought in year 2021. This is on Sheet1.

On Sheet2 I want to get listed unique products (that I have managed to do) and how many of each unique product I have bought inside the country (home) and how many I bought outside the country (abroad) and how many I bought together outside and inside my country.

I got some numbers as a results of trying with different formulas but then I wanted to see if the results are correct and everything stopped :(

basically should products bought abroad plus products bought home equal to total product bought.

At the end I decided to use the query formula to achieve my goal because it is most easy to understand due to the similarity of its select statement to english language.

So, I composed these 3 formulas:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:N,"SELECT B, SUM(G) WHERE L Matches 'Metro|Farmah|Mulackal|Interspar Graz' group by B LABEL SUM(G) 'ABROAD'",0)

=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:N,"SELECT SUM(G) WHERE NOT L Matches 'Metro|Farmah|Mulackal|Interspar Graz' group by B LABEL SUM(G) 'HOME'",0)

=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:N,"SELECT SUM(G) group by B LABEL SUM(G) 'TOTAL'",0)
```

But my problem is that abroad + home doesn't give total :(

I also had problems omitting title row of query formula results what I also haven't succeeded or it was reacting very whimsically by adding a blank row before results of query etc... But this is not the main urgent think.

The main urgent thing is to get correct result of calculations on which I can really that are absolutely correct amounts equal to what I get by manual check for random product from the sheet.

Any idea please?

I don't mind if others formulas are used instead of query like for instance sumif or arrayformula(sumif or sumproduct or whatever as long as the thing works as expected.

This is the link of the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7H7eSeQU7E6VrwhfveqhSyguKmHpe3PKTdfhdW716c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:G, (REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!L2:L, 
 "Metro|Farmah|Mulackal|Interspar Graz")={TRUE, FALSE})*Sheet1!G2:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col7),sum(Col8),sum(Col6) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col7)'ABROAD',sum(Col8)'HOME',sum(Col6)'TOTAL'"))
```

[image]

Comment: more explanation of the formula would be very much appreciated because I want to make spreadsheet for my accounting needs where I plan to enter all the records of different transactions like what was bought, when it was bhought, where it was bhought, including how much VAT, when it was sold, to whom it was sold, for how much it was sold, how it was paid (bank transfere, cash or credit card, etc, etc) and then I plan to generate different views and reports by the use of query formula and I would really appreciate if you could kindly explain what all those curly brackets mean and why so many sum

Comment: why you used column numbers and why not column letters? Is it better like this? Letters couldn't work? Why so many sums in select statement like sum(Col7), sum(Col8), sum(Col6), why where Col1 is not null? Col1 shouldn't be null ever. If you have time I would really appreciate. Thnx.

Comment: Why my approach with 3 querry formula didn't work? If you have time I would really appreciate because what you showed me is not the end of the story. Final result of that spreadsheet has to be report to the goverment eviromental agency how many packing materials like plastic, paper, styropor, carton, tin, glass etc, was brought to my country along with merchandise bought abroad and will one day end up in garbage. On the basis of this report will then goverment chrge me enviromental tax for burdening the enviroment. So I have to weigh each product and specify its neto and brut weigh in other sh

Comment: then use the specification of packing materials from other sheet in this first one to sum total how many of each packing material was given to the enviroment in last year and then for this year same report quarterly. So, I would like to understand in details what you did to be able to apply it again by my self and tweak it if neccessary.

Comment: @kavi when using curly brackets {} we construct array (artificial range). in this case we took B2:G range and appended 2 more columns which are generated with REGEXMATCH so we end up with 8 columns. now for the Col references... whenewer you use cunstructed virtual array {}, QUERY does not work with standard column referencing an we need to use Col references

Comment: @kavi here is explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O5s5ZuRvxDfbE_5tfCqq9KXFwShYtBg3BjcCgTubXMo/edit#gid=810414204

Comment: ok, thank you for the explanation. Is possible to get one more sentence why 3 querry formulas as I compesed them don't give right result? Why it has to be soo complicated with helping columns? Can't it be simpler?

Comment: @kavi your 3-query-formula solution produces wrong result because each query outputs different items in different orders so by the time you reach 2nd query its all lost. you can see this if you include B column in your 2nd and 3rd query. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DqT2yT1haWaLT8tEy4aZx_zfHxq-oGWoItl4L_8K8jg/edit#gid=810414204

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your time and dedication. I wouldn't expect such a behaviour of query formula in my wildest dreams. This is very unwanted, unstable and unpredictable behaviour :( Any Idea why?

Comment: I would like to include criteria where M < date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/7/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") but can't figure it out what column number gets a column M if I include it in your formula :( pls help

Comment: @kavi if your range is `Sheet1!A2:M` then M column is `Col13`. if your range is `Sheet1!B2:M` then M column is `Col12`

Comment: yes, I figured it out by trying before I saw your answer :)
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:M, (REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!L2:L, 
 "Metro|Farmah|Mulackal|Interspar Graz")={TRUE, FALSE})*Sheet1!G2:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col13),sum(Col14),sum(Col6) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  and
  Col12 < date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/7/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col13)'ABROAD',sum(Col14)'HOME',sum(Col6)'TOTAL'"))

Comment: but now I have the problem of checking if 1stHalfOf21 + 2ndHalfOf21 = WholeOf21 because some items are bought only in 1stHalf21 and some are bought only in 2ndHalf21 and lines mismatch and I can't double check it with =if(('1stHalf21'!B2+'2ndHalf21'!B2)=Whole21!B2,"OK","WRONG") in
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vRBdGLogIvEeb9nCp_9TsfLp1BglGwQqm56FqXRT9KI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @kavi see F2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZ7M33sGQPGafCde0ma9yH6nzmNP0MAWxSSpBQ43HYo/edit#gid=879799201

Comment: Briliant! :) I would never figure it out by my self. You really are a master with all aces in your sleve ;) I'd never thought of ifna formula :) Thanks!